# How to call a JavaScript function within a JSP tag attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el

I have a customized tag attribute called **urlStat**, having a dynamic value, so i created a function dedicated to determine the attribute value as follow:

```
function getTag() {
            console.log("-------------SUCCESS---------------");
            var questionId = ${question.idQuestion};
            var values = {};
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${tags}">
                values['${item.key}'] = '${item.value}';
            </c:forEach>

            return values[questionId];
        }
```

**Ps: tags is a Map.**

And i called the method within the attribute **urlStat**:

```
<ser:page headerAff="true" navAff="true" footerAff="false"
urlStat= "getTag()">
```

But the code is not executed, i can't even see the success message in the console view.

What's wrong with this solution?

I also tried to read the value directyly from the attribute:

```
urlStat= "${ tags.[question.idQuestion] }"
```

but i'm getting EL parse ERROR.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you can not ensure `getTag()` method executed,due to the browser or application do not know the meaning of attribute `urlStat`

```
<ser:page headerAff="true" navAff="true" footerAff="false"
urlStat= "getTag()">
```

If you want to make this work,you can change to below code:

```
<ser:page headerAff="true" navAff="true" footerAff="false">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    getTag();
   </script>
</ser:page>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer unfortunaly  i don't have the right to do it this way. I will add another proposition in the description above.